# Facebook Comments on a Website (Making it work with diffrent pages on the site)

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-comments

I have set up the facebook comments on a site I am developing. I am working in ASP and have a header and footer. I placed the code in the footer. It shows up and works fine except that each page shows the same comments. I was hoping to have each page have its own comments. Does anyone know how to do this?

example: I comment on the home page, it shows up on the comments for the whole site.

I would also like the comments to show up on the facebook page.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post the code you're using. It's probably a `url` attribute issue. And you cannot post the comments directly on the Facebook Page (when you think about it, that wouldn't make sense because it would lose context). However, depending on the privacy setting of the user, the comment might be displayed on their profile with the link.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a few of your pages in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). My guess is you have a single canonical url for all pages.

Getting comments to show up on your Facebook page is not supported with the comments plugin. You need to create an app and post Open Graph actions to your page to do that.